# scipy to perform a t-test for equality

Tags: scipy, equality, t-test

I am trying to perform a t-test to determine the equality of the means of two samples of data. I understand that I need to perform a t-test with a null hypothesis of difference and reject it:

```
$$ H_0 = \| \mu_1 - \mu_2\| > \delta $$

$$ H_a = \| \mu_1 - \mu_2\| < \delta $$
```

I know scipy has the ttest_ind but this test assumes equality, so it does not work for me.

Is there any way to perform this test directly with scipy? or how could this be done?

Found several examples that require deriving the equations and using the t distribution tables. I am looking for a solution using the built in statistical functions in scipy or another package to reduce the work of verification.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an [equivalence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test), an example of which is "two one-sided tests" (TOST). SciPy does not have something built-in for this, but you can literally perform two one-sided t-tests.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(459324692354693456)
x = rng.normal(size=100)
y = rng.normal(size=100)

delta = 0.5  # "equivalence bound"
# H0: mean of distribution underlying `x` is equal to the mean of
# the distribution underlying `y - delta`.
# (some would replace "equal" with "less than or equal to"
# H1: mean of distribution underlying `x` is greater than the mean of
# the distribution underlying `y - delta`.
res1 = stats.ttest_ind(x, y - delta, alternative='greater')
print(res1)

# the other one-sided test
res2 = stats.ttest_ind(x, y + delta, alternative='less')
print(res2)
```

```
TtestResult(statistic=3.7153030134010545, pvalue=0.00013198904382128585, df=198.0)
TtestResult(statistic=-3.956379347715619, pvalue=5.298494654171639e-05, df=198.0)
```

In the words of [Lakens 2018](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245918770963), "A conclusion of statistical equivalence is warranted when the larger of the two *p* values is smaller than alpha".

`statsmodels` has a function for this, [`ttost_ind`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_ind.html).

```py
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ttost_ind
ttost_ind(x, y, -delta, delta)
```

The first output of `ttost_ind` is the larger of the two p-values, and the remaining two outputs match the two outputs of SciPy above.

```
(0.00013198904382128585,
 (3.715303013401054, 0.00013198904382128585, 198.0),
 (-3.956379347715618, 5.298494654171652e-05, 198.0))
```